# How to prevent default attribute values with angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive which allows content editable divs to work with ng-model. Looks like this

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  require: "ngModel",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    function read() {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
    }

    ngModel.$render = function() {
      element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
    };

    element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
      scope.$apply(read);
    });
   }
};
});
```

however, whenever I use it with `<div contenteditable="false"></div>` to initialize to false, it still defaults to true. My goal is to have blocks of text that I can toggle between editable and uneditable, but am not sure how to override this default behavior without getting hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in the boolean via scope

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            disabled: @disabled
        }
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

           // reference scope.disabled to access attribute
       }
   };
});
```

Then set the disabled property in your HTML element like this.

```
<div contenteditable disabled="false"></div>
```

Comment: I have thought about doing something like that, but I am not sure what to do with the boolean inside the link function. I'm very new to Angular. I know that the link function must implement the three functions inside. I'm not sure, however, how I can make the attribute conditionally applied from within the link function once i get the boolean

Comment: What do you need to apply it to? Have you tried using `ng-disabled`?

Comment: being applied to divs. The goal is to be able to utilize ng-model with divs, which are not natively supported. this directive enables me to do that. Divs are not editable until their content editable property is set. However, I want this property to be false initially. angular seems to ignore this and sets content editable to true. I referenced this tutorial http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: it was a configuration error. Long explanation, but the directive had nothing to do with the issue, as I didn't even attach it to the controller properly. I'm using ServiceNow and so angular configuration works a little differently. I believe that ng-model forced the contenteditable property to be true when I explicitly specified it (even if i specified it as false). If I didn't specify a value for contenteditable, then ng-model would not work at all, even if I changed contenteditable to be true dynamically. I renamed the directive ngContenteditable, actually attached it to controller, and toggle the regular contenteditable attribute and it works fine.